# Remove duplicate from csv using bash / awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk, duplicates

I have a csv file with the format :

```
"id-1"|"A"
"id-2"|"C"
"id-1"|"B"
"id-1"|"D"
"id-2"|"B"
"id-3"|"A"
"id-3"|"A"
"id-1"|"B"
```

I want to group by first column unique id's and concat types in a single row like this:

```
"id-1"|"A:B:D"
"id-2"|"B:C"
"id-3"|"A"
```

I found awk does a great job in handling such scenarios. But all I could achieve is this:

```
"id-1"|"A":"B":"D":"B"
"id-2"|"B":"C"
"id-3"|"A":"A"
```

I used this command:

```
awk -F "|" '{if(a[$1])a[$1]=a[$1]":"$2; else a[$1]=$2;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' OFS="|" file
```

How can I remove the duplicates and also handle the formatting of the second column types?

Comment: Why `"id-2"|"B:C"` instead of `"id-2"|"C:B"` in output when `C` value comes first.

Comment: @anubhava I am also looking for a sorted result list.

Comment: @Qedrix just be aware that any awk solution using the `in` operator (e.g. `for (i in array)`) unless it's gawk and sets `sorted_in` will not produce sorted output - if the output looks like it IS sorted, that's pure coincidence with your specific data set and you can be sure it will not be with other input.

Answer (score 2):

quick fix:

```
$ awk -F "|" '!seen[$0]++{if(a[$1])a[$1]=a[$1]":"$2; else a[$1]=$2;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' OFS="|" file 
"id-1"|"A":"B":"D"
"id-2"|"C":"B"
"id-3"|"A"
```

- `!seen[$0]++` will be true only if line was not already seen

If second column should all be within double quotes

```
$ awk -v dq='"' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
                 !seen[$0]++{a[$1]=a[$1] ? a[$1]":"$2 : $2}
                 END{for (i in a){gsub(dq,"",a[i]); print i, dq a[i] dq}}' file
"id-1"|"A:B:D"
"id-2"|"C:B"
"id-3"|"A"
```

Comment: should not it be `"B:C"` in the 2nd line?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am not sorting it, hopefully OP will clarify if that is a requirement

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and gensub() and sorted_in:

```
$ awk -F'|' '
    { a[$1][gensub(/"/,"","g",$2)] }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (i in a) {
            c = 0
            for (j in a[i]) {
                printf "%s%s", (c++ ? ":" : i "|\""), j
            }
            print "\""
        }
    }
' file
"id-1"|"A:B:D"
"id-2"|"B:C"
"id-3"|"A"
```

The output rows and columns will both be string-sorted (i.e. alphabetically by characters) in ascending order.

Comment: This is best answer here. Though I don't understand how it got `B:C` instead of `C:B` since `C` appeared first in input.

Comment: Pure coincidence. The `in` operator visits the array indices in hash order (or other randomness but that's the usual...) so the output could've been in any order.

Comment: @anubhava The OP just added a comment that she wanted the output sorted so I've add the`sorted_in` statement to take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Short GNU **datamash** + **tr** solution:

```
datamash -st'|' -g1 unique 2 <file | tr ',' ':'
```

The output:

```
"id-1"|"A":"B":"D"
"id-2"|"B":"C"
"id-3"|"A"
```

**----------**

In case if *between-item* double quotes should be eliminated - use the following alternative:

```
datamash -st'|' -g1 unique 2 <file | sed 's/","/:/g'
```

The output:

```
"id-1"|"A:B:D"
"id-2"|"B:C"
"id-3"|"A"
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** + **sort** solution:

```
awk -F'|' '{ gsub(/"/,"",$2); a[$1]=b[$1]++? a[$1]":"$2:$2 }
           END{ for(i in a) printf "%s|\"%s\"\n",i,a[i] }' <(sort -u file)
```

The output:

```
"id-1"|"A:B:D"
"id-2"|"B:C"
"id-3"|"A"
```

Answer (score 0):

For sample, input below one will work, but unsorted

**One-liner**

```
# using two array ( recommended )
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}!seen[$1,$2]++{a[$1] = ($1 in a ? a[$1] ":" : "") $2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' infile

# using regexp 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{ a[$1] = $1 in a ? ( a[$1] ~ ("(^|:)"$2"(:|$)") ? a[$1] :  a[$1]":"$2  ) : $2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
"id-1"|"A"
"id-2"|"C"
"id-1"|"B"
"id-1"|"D"
"id-2"|"B"
"id-3"|"A"
"id-3"|"A"
"id-1"|"B"

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}!seen[$1,$2]++{a[$1] = ($1 in a ? a[$1] ":" : "") $2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' infile
"id-1"|"A":"B":"D"
"id-2"|"C":"B"
"id-3"|"A"    

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{ a[$1] = $1 in a ? ( a[$1] ~ ("(^|:)"$2"(:|$)") ? a[$1] :  a[$1]":"$2  ) : $2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' infile
"id-1"|"A":"B":"D"
"id-2"|"C":"B"
"id-3"|"A"
```

Better Readable:

Using regexp

```
awk 'BEGIN{
           FS=OFS="|"
     }
     { 
           a[$1] =$1 in a ?(a[$1] ~ ("(^|:)"$2"(:|$)") ? a[$1] : a[$1]":"$2):$2
     }
     END{
           for(i in a)
              print i,a[i]
     }
     ' infile
```

Using two array

```
awk 'BEGIN{
          FS=OFS="|"
     }
     !seen[$1,$2]++{ 
             a[$1] = ($1 in a ? a[$1] ":" : "") $2
     }
  END{
           for(i in a)
               print i,a[i]
     }' infile
```

> Note: you can also use `!seen[$0]++`, it will use entire line as index, but in case in your real data, if
>   you want to prefer some other column, you may prefer `!seen[$1,$2]++`,
>   here column1 and column2 are used as index